# React useEffect unexpected reference to the latest props values on unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures, react-effects

The following component includes an `useEffect` that should run on mount and then cleanup the effect:

```
const Group = ({
  children,
  accessor,
  disabled = false,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  accessor: Accessor
  disabled?: boolean
}) => {
  const dispatch = useEditorDispatch()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (accessor.length === 1 && field === 'audienceExtension') return
    const attribute = `-${field}`
    console.log(`on mount ${accessor}`)
    dispatch({
      type: 'setError',
      payload: {
        message: 'is empty',
        attribute,
        accessor,
      },
    })

    return () => {
    console.log(`on unmount ${accessor}`)
      dispatch({
        type: 'setError',
        payload: { message: null, attribute, accessor },
      })
    }
  }, [])
```

The component tree is build by including `Group`s inside `Group`s. When a `Group` mounts I correctly see the `accessor` value (incremental) but whenever a `Group` unmounts the console logs the latest `accessor` value so not the one related to the unmounted `Group`. I was expecting the returned closure to capture the props of each `Group` and then run the `dispatch` with the correct values but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the `accessor` value that exists outside the function, and getting whatever value it happens to have at unmount time. To capture the on-mount value, I'd define a variable at the start of `useEffect`, and use that in the return funtion - add a `const accessorAtStartOfEffect = accessor` right next to `const attribute`.

Comment: Still capturing the latest `accessor` value